# Python 2.7 / PySide2: Make QGraphicsPathItem selectable without displaying the "selection box"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qgraphicsitem, pyside2

I have an issue I can't find any solution to.
I have a custom QGraphicsPathItem class inheriting from both QGraphicsPathItem and QGraphicsItem so it can be selected.
The selection part works perfectly, but my issue is that a "selection box" appears when it is selected

[image]

which is very annoying and I can't find a solution to get rid of it. I would like the user to see the edge is selected by customizing the paint method, not by having this thing. By the way, I would like to say that all the other QGraphicsItems in my view are not behaving like that when selected....

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your question is how to eliminate the "selection box" or how to change the "selection box"?

Comment: How to eliminate it.